# How to negate a filter in ablFilter used in progress

Tags: javascript, rest, openedge, progress-4gl

I am using filter to hit one BE using the below filter.

```
{"tableref":"eLifeC","ablfilter":"(Cycle EQ '5YRS' OR Cycle EQ 'AC' OR Cycle EQ 'ALAR' OR Cycle EQ 'LXVC')"}
```

From these filters I will get data which only matches my conditions.
Is there any way to get data by negating this filter?
I don't want to use NE in place of EQ, I want to negate whole filter statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way. Are you using the Business Entities / Data Object Services generated by PDSOE?

You will have to implement this in the ABL by adding NOT ( ) around the ablfilter in your relevant fill method there.